# Margin value type in resources

Tags: xaml, styles, staticresource

I want to set margin as default for all page. For height i used

```
    <System:Double x:Key="Height">20</System:Double>
```

But margin is '0,2,0,0' what the type i have to use?

I don't want to use style and setter.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For `Margin` you want the `Thickness` attributes to set it, so instead of a System:Double try;

```
<Thickness x:Key="Height" Left="0" Top="2" Right="0" Bottom="0" />

<Button Margin="{StaticResource Height}" Content="Hey I have a Margin now"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used that in WinRT and got an error: `WMC0100: XAML Thickness type cannot be constructed.`. Solved with `<Thickness x:Key="Height">0,2,0,0</Thickness>`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238734/xaml-margin-in-resources

Comment: @stephenhosking set it like shown in my example with defined Left=, Right=, etc, not as a string as you show.

Answer (score 4):

Try this simplified way of defining Margin as a resource.

```
    <Thickness x:Key="MarginCustom1">100</Thickness> <!--Sets L/T/R/B to 100-->
    <Thickness x:Key="MarginCustom2">10,20</Thickness> <!--Sets L/R to 10 and T/B to 20 -->
    <Thickness x:Key="MarginCustom3">10,10,10,10</Thickness> <!--Sets L/T/R/B respectively-->
```