# XAML Margin in resources

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

How do I define XAML margin in Windows universal app resources? I tried to define it as

```
<Thickness x:Key="MyMargin" Left="10" Top="20" Right="10" Bottom="20" />
```

by this does not compile, I get

XamlCompiler error WMC0100: XAML Thickness type cannot be constructed. In order to to be constructed in XAML, a type cannot be abstract, interface, nested, generic or a struct, and must have a public default constructor

Comment: possible duplicate of [Margin value type in resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805072/margin-value-type-in-resources)

Comment: I didn't see your snippet at first, but that's correct. I'll swing back to this in a minute.

Comment: They way you had is correct, I'm going to guess it has something to do with how you're using it? Do you have it in a resource dictionary? Or at the instance level? Or what?

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for Windows XAML is as follows:

```
<Thickness x:Key="myMargin">10,20,10,20</Thickness>
```

which could be simplified to:

```
<Thickness x:Key="myMargin">10,20</Thickness>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had it working by binding it to a String:

```
<x:String  x:Key="MarginLeftPage" >120,0,0,0</x:String>
[...]
Grid Margin="{StaticResource MarginLeftPage}">
```